# A dense subalgebra of $C(X)$ that separates points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Any idea how to do this problem:

If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $A$ a subalgebra of $C(X)$  , where $C(X)$ is the algebra of all continuous functions, such that $A$ contains the constant functions. Show that $A$ is dense in $C(X)$ iff $A$ separate points in X.

Comment: This is a classical theorem in analysis. Is this homework? If that is the case you should mention explicitly.

Comment: Who assigns the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem as a homework problem?

Comment: one direction is Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, but I need to prove this direction: A is dense in C(X) then it separate points in X. thanx for the comments.

Comment: it is not HW, but it is from my Prof. suggested questions for the qualifying exams.

Comment: Cite the appropriate theorem to the effect that $C(X)$ separates points. Then every dense subspace of $C(X)$ also must separate points.

Answer (score 4):

As you said in the comments, one direction is Stone-Weierstrass. For the other direction, suppose $A$ is a dense subalgebra of $C(X)$, and let $x,y\in X$. Take any function $f\in C(X)$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ (e.g., using Urysohn's Lemma).

By density of $A$, there exists $g\in A$ such that $\Vert g-f\Vert_{\infty}<|f(x)-f(y)|/2$, where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$ is the uniform norm. Then
$$|g(x)-f(x)|\leq\Vert g-f\Vert_\infty<|f(x)-f(y)|/2$$ so
$$|g(y)-f(x)|\geq |f(x)-f(y)|-|f(y)-g(y)|>|f(x)-f(y)|/2,$$
thus $g(x)\neq g(y)$, so $A$ separates points of $X$.